# How to check if {{@index}} is even or odd in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm iterating through an array, but I want to change the div color according to whether the index is odd or even.

Handlebars is not recognizing `{{@index}}` within an `if` statement, such as this:

```
{{#each org as |building i|}}
   {{#if (isEven {{@index}})}}
     ...
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

the `isEven` is a helper I created to check. It works well, but I can't seem to pass the index to it.

Please keep in mind that I'm using Express Handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the brackets around `@index`

```
{{#if (isEven @index)}}
     ...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: It didn't work unfrotunately

Comment: @SadCoder: What isn't working about it? Do you get an error?